# Iterate over certain rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing the origin and destination of flights, like this:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yei8W.png)

And I want to iterate just over a set of rows that start or end with certain cities. Let's say, I just want to iterate over flights starting or ending at JFK or MEX.

Should I use iloc?

Comment: df.loc[df.Origin.isin(['JFK','MEX'])]

Comment: Does this take into account destination too? I would like to iterate not only through flights that start at some airport, but also through flights that end and those airports

Comment: I have write it into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Origin'].isin(["JFK", "MEX"]) | df['Destination'].isin(["JFK", "MEX"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , You can using `groupby` with `agg` `first` and `last`

```
s=df.groupby('Flight').Origin.agg(['first','Last'])
s=s.isin(["JFK", "MEX"]).any(axis=1)
yourdf=df.loc[df.Flight.isin(s[s].index).copy()
```